# CSS font cross browser compatibility

Tags: css, fonts, cross-browser

Ive read a bunch of tutorials on css cross compatibility which mentioned css reset sheets and a few other techniques, but I have yet to be able to create a website which has the font look the exact same on multiple browsers.  I've switched from pt to px and incorporated a few other techniques which helped a little.  Anyone know any better techniques?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to deal with css browser compatibility?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808902/what-is-the-correct-way-to-deal-with-css-browser-compatibility)

Comment: what font/weight/ are you using? you're going to want a very robust font stack

Comment: For some I don't declare anything, others I've used bold and italic.  Font family I've been using Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif

Comment: Look into @font-face or [cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/)

Comment: pt is for print and should never be used for a web page font.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the font to look *exactly* the same (size and all) and you are talking only about headers, then you might want to try using images.

Better, though, would be using `@font-face` and some generated fonts.

Check out FontSquirrel, which produces individual font files for several browers.

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how exact you are talking, but it's never going to be exactly (to the pixel) the same in every browser. For example, I've noticed that OS X tends to make fonts wider (due to how it anti-aliases the text) than on Windows. Different browsers render fonts, even the same font, slightly differently, which can sometimes add up to several pixels, depending on your layout.

Comment: I understand that.  I'll clarify my question.  I just want to be able to open them in multiple browsers and and be able to say, "yeah, theyre the same font".  I don't want them to be pixel for pixel.

Answer (score 0):

typekit might be also a solution for you beside those ones already mentioned.

https://typekit.com/

You must be aware that the users machine can only display the font you have choosen if they actually have these fonts on their computer.

f.e `font-family: "Super Font", Helvetica, sans-serif;`

If you have choosen a font called "Super Font" the users machine won't display this exact font, cause they might not have it on their machine. As declaired in your CSS the user machine will now have a look at the alternative "Helvetica", which the most of computers have on their machine, so "Helvetica" is gonna be displayed. If not even "Helvetica" is available the users machine will display a sans-serif font.

Here's a list of common fonts: [Link](http://www.ampsoft.net/webdesign-l/WindowsMacFonts.html)

You already see, that they differ a bit in their look and font-weight cause they get rendered differently as Nate B already mentioned.

If you want to use your "Super Font" have a look at http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface as Jason Gennaro already recommended. There you'll be able not to only choose a font from a lot of free fonts but also use the @font-face generator to upload your own font and get all you need to build them right into your CSS, so that every machine will be able to display them (as far as @font-face is supported, [Link](http://webfonts.info/wiki/index.php?title=@font-face_browser_support)). Even if it's already well supported, always declare a fallback font.

And here's a good blog post about the different ways to declare a font-size: [Link](http://kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/)

If you wanna dig a bit deeper and find out how to control the font-size over different devices, check out this article: [Link](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/howtosizetextincss)

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I'm interested in how sites like google, facebook and hulu render the same fonts in every browser.  For the most part, their sites look almost the exact same in any browser.